# phoenix-core can't install because of omid error

Tags: java, maven, gradle, apache-phoenix

I am trying to upgrade my phoenix-core library from 5.0.0.-HBase-2.0 to 5.1.3

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-core
implementation 'org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:5.1.3'
```

When I attempt to build the project, I always get a slew of errors around omid, but they all basically say the same thing, "bad module name: expected='omid-hbase-client-hbase2.x' found='omid-hbase-client-hbase1.x'"

```
   > Could not resolve org.apache.omid:omid-hbase-client-hbase2.x:1.0.2.
 Required by:
     project : > org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:5.1.3
    > Could not resolve org.apache.omid:omid-hbase-client-hbase2.x:1.0.2.
       > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: org.apache.omid:omid-hbase-client-hbase1.x:1.0.2 Errors: bad module name: expected='omid-hbase-client-hbase2.x' found='omid-hbase-client-hbase1.x'
  > Could not resolve org.apache.omid:omid-hbase-coprocessor-hbase2.x:1.0.2.
```

I have search high and low on google, and can't find a reason for this.  I have tried clearing everything and nothing helps.